# Putting 12 balls of different colors in 4 urns, 3 balls in each.

Tags: probability, combinatorics, inclusion-exclusion

5 red, 4 green and 3 blue balls are put in 4 boxes so that every box has exactly 3 balls.

Find the probability that:

1. At least 1 box has a ball of every color;
2. Only 1 box has a ball of every color

I've tried to compute the probability of at least 1 box having an RGB as follows:
$$\mathbb{P}(\geq 1 RGB)=\frac{\binom{5}{1}\cdot\binom{4}{1}\cdot\binom{3}{1}\cdot\frac{9!}{(3!)^3}}{\frac{12!}{(3!)^4}}=\frac{3}{11}$$
since we choose an RGB and then put the remaining 9 balls into boxes at random.

The problem is, I don't know whether I need to account for the allocation of boxes. If, say, we choose one box to put the RGB into and the total number of ways to allocate boxes is $4!$, then the $\mathbb{P}(\geq 1 RGB)$ will multiply by $\frac{4}{4!}$ and be equal to $\frac{2}{11}$.

No progress with the other probability so far.

From the examples found online, this problem may be solved with the inclusion-exclusion formula, but I struggle to figure out what the events $A_1,\dots,A_n$ are in this model.

How do I apply the inclusion-exclusion formula here or is there any other way to obtain the probabilities in question?

Comment: Are the boxes distinct?

Comment: @ParclyTaxel I don't think they are. It is not in any way stated in the problem. The balls of the same color are not distinct either, I believe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Line up the urns from left to right.  There are
$$\binom{12}{3}\binom{9}{3}\binom{6}{3}\binom{3}{3}$$
to distribute three balls to each of the four urns.

*An urn with a ball of each color*:  There are four ways to select the urn which will receive a ball of each color, five ways to select a red ball, four ways to select a green ball, and three ways to select a blue ball for that urn.  There are $\binom{9}{3}\binom{6}{3}\binom{3}{3}$ ways to distribute the remaining nine balls to the remaining three urns so that they each receive three balls.  Hence, there are
$$\binom{4}{1}\binom{5}{1}\binom{4}{1}\binom{3}{1}\binom{9}{3}\binom{6}{3}\binom{3}{3}$$
such distributions.

*Two urns with a ball of each color*:  There are $\binom{4}{2}$ ways to select the two urns which will receive a ball of each color.  There are five ways to select a red ball, four ways to select a green ball, and three ways to select a blue ball for the leftmost of those two urns.  There are four ways to select a red ball, three ways to select a green ball, and two ways to select a blue ball for the rightmost of those two urns.  There are $\binom{6}{3}\binom{3}{3}$ ways to distribute the remaining balls to the remaining two urns so that they each receive three balls.  There are
$$\binom{4}{2}\binom{5}{1}\binom{4}{1}\binom{3}{1}\binom{4}{1}\binom{3}{1}\binom{2}{1}\binom{6}{3}\binom{3}{3}$$
such distributions.

*Three urns with a ball of each color*:  There are $\binom{4}{3}$ ways to select which three urns will receive a ball of each color.  There are five ways to select a red ball, four ways to select a green ball, and three ways to select a blue ball for the leftmost of those three urns.  There are four ways to select a red ball, three ways to select a green ball, and two ways to select a blue ball for the rightmost of those three urns.  There are three ways to select a red ball, two ways to select a green ball, and one way to select a blue ball for the middle of those three urns.  All three of the remaining balls must be placed in the other urn.  Hence, there are
$$\binom{4}{3}\binom{5}{1}\binom{4}{1}\binom{3}{1}\binom{4}{1}\binom{3}{1}\binom{2}{1}\binom{3}{1}\binom{2}{1}\binom{1}{1}\binom{3}{3}$$
such distributions.

It is not possible for all four urns to each receive a ball of each color since there are only three blue balls.  By the [Inclusion-Exclusion Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle), the probability that there is at least one ball of each color is
$$\frac{\binom{4}{1}\binom{5}{1}\binom{4}{1}\binom{3}{1}\binom{9}{3}\binom{6}{3}\binom{3}{3} - \binom{4}{2}\binom{5}{1}\binom{4}{1}\binom{3}{1}\binom{4}{1}\binom{3}{1}\binom{2}{1}\binom{6}{3}\binom{3}{3} + \binom{4}{3}\binom{5}{1}\binom{4}{1}\binom{3}{1}\binom{4}{1}\binom{3}{1}\binom{2}{1}\binom{3}{1}\binom{2}{1}\binom{1}{1}\binom{3}{3}}{\dbinom{12}{3}\dbinom{9}{3}\dbinom{6}{3}\dbinom{3}{3}}$$

Comment: Isn't $\binom{3}{1}$ missing from the number of distributions for "An urn with a ball of each color"?

Comment: @pieinthesky  Thank you for pointing out the error.

Comment: I understand, to obtain the probability of exactly one RGB, I need to multiply the second summand in the numerator by 2 and the last by 3. Is it correct?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.